# Support Libraries vs Normal Libraries in Android

Tags: android

How are support libraries different from normal libraries in Android, except the fact that Support libraries can run the app on wider range of devices? Shouldn't one use Support libraries instead of normal libraries, as support libraries can make the app run on a wider range of devices with the same functionality as that of normal libraries?

Comment: What do you mean by a normal library? 
Yes it is correct that the Support libraries help you create consistent design across several versions, but technically it is a normal android library also.

Answer (score 0):

Support libraries are normal libraries.  They're just a set of libraries written by Google that backport features of newer Android devices to older ones.  There's nothing special about them, "Support libraries" is the name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but then why are Support libraries included in the Gradle dependencies, unlike other libraries? Also, for example, why do we have an "android.app.ActionBar" library rather than just having the "android.support.v7.app.ActionBar" library when they both have the same function and the latter can make the app run on a larger range of devices? @GabeSechan

Comment: All libraries are in dependencies, unless you have a weird setup. Android.app.actionbar isn't a library, it's a class. It's pay of the android framework. The support one is a ballet of it to older devices that uses the base one when possible.